# Why am I getting array how to get string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, match

If I have textarea with `id leavepost` and hidden div `id display`
After # I got hidden div and word with # in var name
But when I want to sent itvia ajax to sul file it sends array. 
What is wrong?

```
$("#leavepost").keypress(function(event) {
    var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (key == 35) {
        $('#display').show();
        $('#leavepost').on('keyup', function() {
            var name = $(this).val().match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "d/sul.php",
                data: { su: name },
                success: function(sss)
                {
                    $('#display').html(sss);

                }
            });
        }).keyup();
    }
});
```

Inside sul.php I have:

```
echo $_POST['su'];
$u = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['su']);
```

error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   array given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.match()` returns an array of matching tests.

```
// for example:
"xzxzxz".match(/z/gi)    // => [z,z,z]
"xzxzxz".match(/z/gi)[0] // => "z"
```

Either use `.match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig)[0]` to get the first match.

or you can `.match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig).join(",")` to send all the test matches in a string.

```
// for example
"xzxzxz".match(/z/gi).join(",") // => "z,z,z"
"xzxzxz".match(/z/gi).join("")  // => "zzz"
```

Comment: I dont need to find z or something in your case, I need to find word that is standing next to Z with z.. So from your answer : xzxzxz i need to fin zx,zx

Comment: Can you help me here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822326/replace-var-with-some-new-var-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You use in this code `var name = $(this).val().match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig);` [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and this method return:

> An Array containing the entire match result and any
>   parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no
>   matches.

So you need to work with `$_POST['su'];` variable in your php code as with array

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do it? I am sending request with ajax to sul file wheere I look up does someone exist in database whit word i am typing... word next to # .... So i dont know how can I do it

Comment: please add result of `var_dump($_POST['su']);`. I need to know the structure of this array

Comment: i output me number of strings i type in

Comment: It's great that you got your result.

Comment: Can we go on chat? I need to ask you something I made after the typing to get echos in hidden div from users and I made replace on click with some link but on click it wont replace my #word ....

Comment: I posted new question :/ Not lucky 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822326/replace-var-with-some-new-var-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It is because the JavaScript `match` function returns an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

You need to extract the `name` part from that array. `console.log(name)` will give you the structure of the array.

Comment: Can u help me here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822326/replace-var-with-some-new-var-jquery