# Replace var with some new var jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code to find something from database and output it back if it exists.
Now when I output it back I need to make on click one of those outputs replace that output as var in some other var.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#display').hide();
    $("#leavepost").keypress(function(event) {
        var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (key == 35) {
            $('#display').show();
            $('#leavepost').on('keyup', function() {
                var matches = $(this).val().match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig)[0];
                var name = matches;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "d/sul.php",
                    data: {
                        su: name
                    },
                    success: function(sss) {
                        $('#display').html(sss);
                        $(".adduser").click(function() {
                            var username = $(this).text();
                            var a = username;
                            var username2 = $(this).attr('id');
                            var E = "<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#' >" + a + "</a>";
                            var content = name.replace(name, E);
                            $("#leavepost").html(content);
                            $("#display").hide();
                            $("#leavepost").focus();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }).keyup();
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on class div hides but before that nothings happend... I need to replace #word from var name witdh var E.
Thanks

Comment: I need something like this this is making problem ....
https://jsfiddle.net/6whs6dj4/
It wont replace anything I need first to replace name as "" and then use append to add some html next to text in textarea

Comment: You want this? https://jsfiddle.net/6whs6dj4/2/

Comment: Yeah but why it is not working with this:
var old = $('#leavepost').html();
$("#leavepost").html(old.replace(name,"-"));

Comment: name is typed word in textarea

Comment: Can you provide a more similar fiddle to your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110060/discussion-between-careless-and-daniel-cheung).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely because you used `.html()` in on a `<textarea>` as stated in the discussion.

https://jsfiddle.net/q9gwdLj5/

```
$(function(){
  $("#choices li").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    $("#ta").val($("#ta").val().replace("#thisperson", name));
  })
})
```

Changing the `.html()` bit with `.val()` will fix the problem.